# Cartesian product in R

Tags: dataframe, cartesian-product

What is the fastest way to find cartesian product of two lists in R? For example, I have:

x <- c(a,b,c,d)  y <- c(1, 2, 3)

I need to make from them the following data.frame:

```
   x y
1  a 1
2  a 2
3  a 3
4  b 1
5  b 2
6  b 3
7  c 1
8  c 2
9  c 3
10 d 1
11 d 2
12 d 3
```

Comment: x cross y or y cross x?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming x cross y, this would be one way:

```
# Tideyverse solution
library(tidyr)
x <- letters[1:4]
y <- c(1, 2, 3)
tibble(
    x = x,
    y = list(y)
) %>% 
    unnest(y)
    # A tibble: 12 x 2
   x         y
   <chr> <dbl>
 1 a         1
 2 a         2
 3 a         3
 4 b         1
 5 b         2
 6 b         3
 7 c         1
 8 c         2
 9 c         3
10 d         1
11 d         2
12 d         3
# Base R solution
expand.grid(y = y, x = x)
   y x
1  1 a
2  2 a
3  3 a
4  1 b
5  2 b
6  3 b
7  1 c
8  2 c
9  3 c
10 1 d
11 2 d
12 3 d
```